# How prove this algebraically?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinations

Let $a,b,x,y$ be nonnegative integers.  By way of using generating functions, prove that 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x+b \\
a
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
y+a \\
b\\
\end{pmatrix}
 = \sum_{i=0}^{\min\{a,b\}}
\begin{pmatrix}
x+y+i \\
i\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
y \\
b-i\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
a-i\\
\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$

Comment: I would love to see a combinatorial proof as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is a starter. We show OPs claim in the special case:
>   \begin{align*}
> x&=a\\
> y&=b
> \end{align*}
>
> The following is valid for $a,b\geq 0$
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=0}^{\min\{a,b\}}\binom{a+b+i}{i}\binom{a}{i}\binom{b}{i}=\binom{a+b}{a}\binom{a+b}{b}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

We show the validity by successively using two aspects:

- *[Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)*
  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{j\geq 0}\binom{m}{j}\binom{n}{r-j}=\binom{m+n}{r}\qquad\qquad m,n,r\geq 0
  \end{align*}
  to *separate* $m$ and $n$ and
- the identity
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{r}=\binom{n}{r}\binom{n-r}{n-k}\qquad\qquad\quad n,k,r \geq 0
  \end{align*}
  since this *shuffling* reduces the number of occurrences of $k$.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i\geq 0}&\binom{a+b+i}{a+b}\binom{a}{i}\binom{b}{i}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{i\geq 0}\sum_{j\geq 0}\binom{a+b}{a+b-j}\binom{i}{j}\binom{a}{i}\binom{b}{i}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{i\geq 0}\sum_{j\geq 0}\binom{a+b}{a+b-j}\binom{a}{j}\binom{a-j}{a-i}\binom{b}{i}\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{j\geq 0}\binom{a+b-j}{a}\binom{a+b}{a+b-j}\binom{a}{j}\tag{5}\\
> &=\binom{a+b}{a}\sum_{j\geq 0}\binom{b}{j}\binom{a}{j}\tag{6}\\
> &=\binom{a+b}{a}\binom{a+b}{b}\tag{7}\\
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim (1) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we simplify things by adding zeros by reindexing ($i\geq 0$)
- In (3) we apply Vandermonde's identity to $\binom{a+b+i}{a+b}$
- In (4) we apply *shuffling* to $\binom{a}{i}\binom{i}{j}$
- In (5) we apply Vandermonde's identity to $\sum_{i\geq 0}\binom{a-j}{a-i}\binom{b}{i}$
- In (6) we apply *shuffling* to $\binom{a+b}{a+b-j}\binom{a+b-j}{a}$
- In (7) we apply Vandermonde's identity to $\sum_{j\geq 0}\binom{b}{b-j}\binom{a}{j}$